# rails top level domain names and subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, cross-domain, subdomain

I wanna ask on how to implement top level domain using rails.

I am working on a webapp that will allow the user to have a subdomain (by default it will be their username). Right now it is all set and working.

But I want the user to have an option of using their own domain name instead of being a subdomain of my webapp.

Any Ideas, or suggestions?
Or a link that points to a page that will help me understand things like this, better.

Basically I want the user to input the "domain name" the he/she bought into my webapp and then my app will take care of that specified domain name.

and also the NAMESERVER if necessary.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it sounds like you're asking more of a DNS question than a Rails question. Maybe you need to set the [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) of your user domain's DNS record.

Comment: Do you know how to handle the DNS setup vai RoR?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this was a blog site and if traffic went to `http://mysubdomain.yourdomain.com` you would look up the user by looking up `mysubdomain` and then looking up the posts for that user.

For a top level domain you'd do something very similar. You'd inspect `request.host` in the controller (or some other method of `Request` specific to Rails (I use Merb, so that's my example)) and then find the user based on that, assuming of course `request.host` didn't match your own app's domain.

As far as how you handle the data goes, I'd probably create a `users_domains` if users can have more than one domain, or if you have a "blogs" table then just tack a `custom_domain` column on it.